# ASP.NET mailto: misfunction

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, mailto

I have a HyperLink set up to use mailto, but it would seem that it's calling inside the root folder.
*~/Admin/mailto:email@stackoverflow.com*

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Email", "mailto:{0}")%>'
               Text='<%#Eval("Email")%>' ID="emailLink" />
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try to

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%#Bind("Email", "mailto:{0}") %>' Text='<%#Bind("Email") %>' runat="server" ID="emailLink"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Good luck!

Comment: It didn't work... Thanks though. Something weird must be going on.

Comment: Old I know but this worked for me.  I had been trying to get this to work without success.  For anyone else that might run into this, encase this with <asp:TemplateField> and <ItemTemplate> tags.