# HTML MAILTO hyperlink doesn't respond

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, oracle10g, mailto

My hyperlink doesn't open up an email with my database text value.

I have a previous application that uses this exact format and works; however, for this application it doesn't.

One of the many examples I have referenced is: [ASP.NET mailto: misfunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895667/asp-net-mailto-misfunction)

my Database column name is `email_Own` and so I have tried to `DataItem.email_Own` and `DataItem.email` like other examples show to see if whether the value after DataItem is the database column name or not. **Both don't work.**

**Working EX**

My other application showed an email within a gridview so I am wondering if that is the reason why the coding below worked:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" >
  <ItemTemplate >
     <br /><br />
     Email:  
     <asp:HyperLink id="lnkEmail" cssClass="emailColor" runat="server" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.email") %>' NavigateUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.email","MAILTO:{0}")%>'>
     </asp:HyperLink>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[image]

**Coding that doesn't work:**

Any suggestions for the coding below? This hyperlink is inside a table.

```
<tr>
 <td width="25%">
 <font class="Blackfont" size="2" > <b>Owner Email </b> </font> 
 </td>
 <td>                 
   <asp:HyperLink id="Owner_E" runat="server" text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.email") %>' NavigateUrl='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.email","MAILTO:{0}")%>'Font-Size="10pt"></asp:HyperLink>

</td>
</tr>
```

[image]

The text of the hyperlink shows up correctly when the page loads. Its the linking to mail that isn't working.

I also tried this code snippet instead but the hyperlink doesn't respond as well: `NavigateUrl='<%#Bind("email_Own", "mailto:{0}") %>' Text='<%#Bind("email_Own") %>'`

**FYI:**

I am not sure if this changes anything but I fill the hyperlink in VB.net like so:

```
If Not DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(14) Is DBNull.Value Then
    lnkEmail.Text = DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(14)
End If

where DsAds is a dataset
```

The HTML source code shows this:

Comment: Does taking out the `Font-Size="10pt"` part, or at least putting a space in front of it so it isn't touching the preceding closing single quote, help? It would probably be useful to include the generated HTM for both snippetsL if you can; do your browser's developer tools show the ASP code or the generated HTML equivalent?

Comment: @Alex Poole The font-size line doesn't change with your suggestions. When I inspect the element in the web browser the hyperlink text shows like this `<a id="lnkEmail" style="font-size: 10px;">emailAddress@yahoo.com</a>`

Comment: @AlexPoole see my comment. First comment didn't work with when I did the `@` symbol for your name

Comment: @AlexPoole weird because my other application actually shows the `href="MAILTO:....` when I source view it??!!!

Comment: @AlexPoole I showed in my post how I fill Hyperlink .. if that helps at all

Comment: @AlexPoole I added images above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referenced http://forums.asp.net/t/1071308.aspx?mailto+link+in+textbox

Like so:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="lnkEmail" runat="server" Font-Size="10pt" ></asp:HyperLink>
```

and in Page Load[at end of it] I add:

```
lnkEmail.NavigateUrl = "mailto:" + DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(14)
lnkEmail.Text = DsAds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(14)
```